# can soap client retry the createClient?

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I have created the createClient with node soap. So my question is that if the soapclient create method throw error

```
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
 if (err) {
          count++;
          console.error('got error while creating client retrying',count, err);
  } else {
      client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader);
      soapClient = client;
  }
});
```

then if I call the api again and again can it will call the soap client again if fail for first time keeping in mind all code in one route file

```
/* GET billing information */
router.get('/billlinginfo/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  // 316005001503
  var args = {
    AccountNumber: req.params.id
  };
  soapClient.someCall(args, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      } else {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating soap client in one route file then it will not be created every time when you requires route file.